# Adding to list and incrementing - Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Char

-- Sample test data
testData :: [Movies]
testData = [("Me and My Broken Heart","Rixton"),
            ("It’s My Birthday","will.i.am"),
            ("Problem","Ariana Grande")]

-- record a sale of a track 
record :: [Movies] -> String -> String 
record t a = []
record ((t, a): xs) a a
    | t == a && a == a = [(t,a)]
    | otherwise = record xs a t
```

The correct output should be a modified version of the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, since it seems you're learning, a few notes on style: in a case like this, it is a convention to name *one* sale with a singular form, and the list of them with the plural, that is:

```
type Sale = (String, String, Int)
type Sales = [Sale]
```

Even better, one would often (depending on intended usage and taste) turn `Sale` into a newtype or full ADT, since that gives you more abstraction and type safety.

Second, to your actual question: the behavior you're seeing comes from the order of pattern matching. In your first match,

```
recordSale testData aTitle anArtist = []
```

`testDate` matches *any* list, also non-empty ones, before the second pattern can apply. Change that to

```
recordSale [] _ _ = []
```

and you won't get only empty lists anymore. Additionally, as @Aleksandar notes, you should not forget to keep the init of the list in cases where the list is not empty, but the filter criteria don't match.

Comment: Thanks for your answer its working now but not displaying the rest of the test data. So its showing [("Problem","Ariana Grande",4)] only and not first 2 titles also.

Comment: That is what I addressed in the last line. Take my pattern for the empty list, and Aleksandar's correction for the rest, and it should work. Also, no need to hurry with accepting answers. Wait, test, and then choose what you found suitable.

Comment: Thank you for all the help, I'm new to haskell and this website so still learning.

Answer (score 4):

Haskell is a functional language, and encapsulates stateful modifications to data very well in the type system. The usual way of "mutating" a value in Haskell would be to either use a stateful computation (in the `ST` or `State` `Monad`) or to just use recursion and duplicate the values. I think you should learn the latter first.

The function you used will return `[]` in case `aTitle` and `anArtist` don't match any of the entries in the list. Otherwise it *will* return a list with *one* single element in it, namely the newly modified one.

You need to build up the list incrementally as you traverse it. Remember, you're basically copying it:

`-- record a sale of a track 
recordSale :: [Sales] -> String -> String -> [Sales]
recordSale [] aTitle anArtist = []
recordSale ((title, artist, qty): xs) aTitle anArtist
    | title == aTitle && artist == anArtist = 
              (title, artist, qty+1):recordSale xs aTitle anArtist
    | otherwise = (title,artist,qty):recordSale xs aTitle anArtist`

This should give you the right results. Notice what's different here: you have a recursive call to the function in *both* cases, and in both cases, too, you're appending the current element either modified or unmodified to the list you're building.

You should also think about your data structure. Having tuples with comments is not a very nice way of constructing complex data structures. Try

`data Record = Record { title :: String, artist :: String, quantity :: Integer }`

You could even make a couple of `newtype`s like `newtype Title = Title String`. Remember, creating data types in Haskell is cheap, and you should be doing it constantly.